# Java can't find symbol even though I've defined it

Tags: java, tags, return

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    int rows;
    System.out.print("Number of rows (1-10): ");
    rows = console.nextInt();
    if (rows < 1) {
        rows = 1;
    } else if (rows > 10) {
        rows = 10;
    } else {
        return rows;
    }
```

I keep getting a compiler error that java can't find the symbol "rows".

Comment: You can't `return` from a `void` method.

Comment: `int rows = Math.min(10, Math.max(1, console.nextInt()));`

Comment: Eclipse error message: *"Void methods cannot return a value"* --- Oracle JDK 8 error message: *"error: incompatible types: unexpected return value"* --- Both seem very on point and don't say "can't find symbol". Where do *you* see that error?

Comment: @Jacob G. To be specific, you can't return a _value_ in a void method, you can surely do `return;` to leave a method immediately even for a `void` (though I doubt this really ever needs to be done).

Comment: @Nexevis Good catch, I worded that poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a different error message:

```
Main.java:[18,20] incompatible types: unexpected return value
```

You are trying to return an integer but the main() method has return type void. To return a number, you may use

```
System.exit(rows);
```

But this is unusual. Normally return value 0 of executable programs means "success" and all other numbers indicate an error.